# AIX CMakeTest does not add correct -lpthread

Tags: c++, cmake, pthreads, aix

I am trying to use CMake to compile my project.
I have a dependency on the pthread library.

On my CMakeFile I tried a lot of different options

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -lpthreads")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -pthread -lpthreads")
set(CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT "-lpthreads")
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
```

But in the CheckSymbolExists step it does not add the -lpthread flag:

```
/usr/vacpp/bin/cc   -qthreaded -qalias=noansi -qhalt=e     CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec2302980897.dir/CheckSymbolExists.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec2302980897 -Wl,-brtl,-bnoipath,-bexpall -Wl,-blibpath:
/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/lib:/lib
```

I tested on a separated file using the cc directly and the -qthreaded does not work, but the -lpthread works. Is there a flag for the CMake add the -lpthread to the CheckSymbolExists step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `target_link_libraries` and apply it on your executable.
Simple example on a project using boost::threads :

```
include_directories(
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
include_directories( SYSTEM
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
link_directories(
  ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}
)
add_executable( MyProgram
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main.cpp
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/my_program.cpp
)
target_link_libraries( MyProgram
  ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
  pthread
)
```